# Tracking links contained within a data extension field

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud, hyperlink

I have the following sample content contained within a Data Extension:

```
Welcome home from your holiday at <strong>%%=v(@resort_name)=%%</strong>. 
We hope you had a great time. We would love for you to share your experience
with us and other people who may be interested in a holiday at your resort. 
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat('http://www.domain.com/resort/reviews?whichTab=reviews&resortCode=',@resort_id))=%%" target="_Blank" style="color:#F58220;">Review</a> 
your holiday on domain.com today.
```

To display this content I retrieve it from the Data Extension and then use the TreatAsContent function to display it within the email:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(@Intro_body)=%%
```

However when the email is sent, the links within this content are not tracked.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: This is a frustrating shortcoming/limitation of the SFMC platform that's been discussed a ton on SFSE: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D+httpgetwrap

Comment: So it's a known limitation and i'm not doing something wrong? I am actually okay with that fact - stops me berating myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Currently links contained within a data extension field cannot be tracked. Even if you use the RedirectTo function.